# Rails PG::Error Presentation and Handling of Unique Constraint

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I am developing on Rails 4 with postgres and devise. I have the following User model:

```
# user model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, :use => :slugged

  rolify

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}, :length => { :minimum => 3 },
            :format => { :with => /\A[A-Z0-9a-z\w\b\ \-\_\'\!&@#\.]+\z/i,
              :message => "may contain only alphanumeric characters and common special characters." }
  validates :email, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}, :presence => true, 
            :format => { :with => Devise.email_regexp, :message => "isn't valid"}

  validates :password, length: { in: 6..128 }, on: :create
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..128 }, on: :update, allow_blank: true

  validates :slug, :presence => true

end


# in schema
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "slug"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["slug"], name: "index_users_on_slug", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
```

The fields email and username are unique indices of the users table. My user registration view was created from devise. I create a test account, for instance, with username "test", email "test@example.com", password "123456". I sign out and try to sign up with the same information. I am expecting that the :uniqueness validations to trigger and be rendered on a list of errors alongside the signup form, but instead I get a full-page error with:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
>   DETAIL:  Key (email)=(test@example.com) already exists.

How can I allow this error to bubble up to Rails and be shown as friendly single-line error like "Email is already registered with an account" alongside the sign up form instead of being caught with a big Rails error page?

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the problem. The plugin friendly_id turned out not so friendly. It breaks uniqueness validation and results in 500 internal server errors. I have removed it from my application. Consider using something like ActsAsUrl in the [Stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex) library. I have removed

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username_copy, :use => :slugged
```

and am now using

```
acts_as_url :username, :sync_url => true, :url_attribute => :slug
```

to generate friendly urls.

Comment: I have the same issue and don't use `FriendlyId` with the `User` model